# How can i search for an element without using any loops in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, built-in

I have an array like [1,2,3,4,5,6,7] how can I search for an element without using any loops and built-in methods in `javascript` ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: [find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) , [indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)

Comment: `your_array.indexOf(value) != -1`

Comment: is the array sorted and elements are unique?

Comment: `without any loops` that is impossible

Comment: it is just a normal array but it has only numbers

Comment: What exactly is your usecase? It is not possible to find elements in an array without iterating or using built in methods like `find` `indexOf`

Comment: case is
in array of numbers less than 7, i have to get two numbers which their addition is 7 (like 1+6==7), for that issue the condition is we have to use only one loop  that may be manual or built-in method that loops internally, somehow i reached in getting first number now i have to get the second number that matches the above condition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible, but you must have an JavaScript Object like this:

```
var Obj = {
    'a':1,
    'b':2,
    'c':3,
    'd':4,
    'e':5
};
```

Without search you can access to your element like this:

```
console.log(Obj['a']);
```

Comment: thanks
i added the concept of object and this solved in magical way

Answer (score 2):

You could use a recursive approach and [rest parameters `...`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) for the array, without using some array methods.

```js
function find(search, array) {
    return function check(search, value, ...rest) {
        return search === value || rest.length && check(search, ... rest) || false;
    }(search, ...array);
}

console.log(find(1, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]));
console.log(find(42, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use indexOf method to search for element.
I hope this will help you.

```js
var array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7];
var searchElement = 5;
if(array.indexOf(searchElement)>-1) {
  console.log('element present in array');
} else {
console.log('element not present in array');
}
```

If you don't want to search all the elements. First iterate through all the elements and construct a object. 
The construction of object is one time process and use this object for searching an element.

```js
var array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7];
var obj = {};
for(var i=0;i<array.length;i++)
{
  if(obj.hasOwnProperty(array[i])) 
    continue;
  obj[array[i]] = true;
}
var searchElement = 7;
if(obj[searchElement] == true) {
  console.log("element present");
} else {
  console.log("element not present");
}
```

Comment: This will work but Array.iindexOf() internally loops array in search of element , what i got the task is not to loop either by built-in of by manual coding.

Comment: Yes it will search for all the elements, If you don't want built in function also not to search for all elements. Then construct a dictionary from your input and create a key for every input. And use that key to directly return dict[key]  But for this we should know what will be the values of input. If we don't have control or no idea of inputs then we don't have choice other than using these functions.

Comment: @NovuduSomaSekhar, I have updated with another approach, I hope this what you are expecting.

Answer (score 0):

The find() method returns the value of the first element in the array that satisfies the provided testing function. Otherwise undefined is returned.

```
var array1 = [5, 12, 8, 130, 44];

var found = array1.find(function(element) {
  return element > 10;
});

console.log(found);
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot `search` for an element in `O(1)`, however you can check if an element exist in a `Set`:

```
const set = new Set(array);
if(set.has(3)) console.log("3 is in array");
```